# Firestore snapshot fails in Raspbian OS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron, raspbian

My code runs MacOS, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. However when I run it on Raspbian, I get the error

```
Encountered error: Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0
(node:18099) ExperimentalWarning: The http2 module is an experimental API.
```

my versions are:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node -v
v13.1.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm -v
6.12.1
```

The problem occurs when I set the snapshot for a firebase focument. Thank you guys in advance...

Comment: Your title mentions an Electron app. Electron apps don't use the installed Node runtime, so checking that version isn't really related. Can you be more specific about how you are running this code?

Comment: I mean, I am running it as an npm project. When I change the working OS, I am deleting the node_modules folder, package-lock.json file. Then I install necessary  packages with `npm install` then the app start working, however in Raspberrian, it doesn't. I just install Ubuntu to raspberry pi 4, it's same again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to run an electron js based app on device which has cpu with arm architecture you have to use either `electron@3.0.13` or `electron@5.0.0` . In addition, if are you going to use another library which uses `grpc` , use `electron@5.0.0` . Otherwise you will drown in errors. Just delete the version of electron in packege.json file. Make that line as `electron: "5.0.0"` and delete node_modules with package-lock.json file. After `npm install` you are good to go.